# Parse Json Object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have used below code listing in my Asp.net web form's Page_Load method:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonString = String.Empty;

            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var emplList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Employee>>(jsonString);
            var resp = String.Empty;

            foreach (var emp in emplList)
            {
                resp += emp.name + " \\ ";
                //File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", emp.name.ToString()+"\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(resp));


            File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", resp.ToString() + "\r\n", Encoding.UTF8);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"d:\status\LOL.txt", "Stop it!", Encoding.UTF8);

        }
```

When I send JSON to this aspx file, object receives it and save it into file, read it, but how can I Parse variable 'resp' using JSON object?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do. `resp` is just a string of names from `emplList` like: "Bob \ Tom \ Joe" which is not a JSON object. What are you trying to parse out of it?

Comment: Ok CodingWithSpike yo say to me how can i get JSON object in my asp.net web forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you forget JavaScriptSerializer and use newtownsoft's implementation of working with JSON.  It's faster and real easy to work with.  Documentation on using it is here:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

You can download/install it using Nuget.

Here's a quick code snippet example from their documentation site:

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

Comment: thanks my friend,but how can i get JSON object in my webForm page_Load method?this Solution get JSON object?how can my web form understand JSON object Recieve?

Comment: @BehzadRazzaqi Well, it depends on what you're trying to do.  You can "get" a JSON object in your Page_Load method any number of ways.  You could create it from scratch, using the above code snippet as a guide.  Or you could read it in from a file.  Or you could query a DB and convert it, etc etc.  I'm sure that's not quite what you're asking, so I'll need some more details of what exactly you need to do to provide more guidance.